# Joomla 5 = cron not working

Tags: joomla, cron

I'm running CiviCRM 5.70.2 and Joomla! 5.0.3 w/ PHP 8.2 ... all seems to be working as expected with the only problem being the cron.

In administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php ...

1. To get it to run I had to first define CIVICRM_CONFDIR
2. Then I'm seeing errors in debug mode "Attempted to load class "JFactory" from the global namespace."   ... which seems like it's not seeing Joomla's compatibility plugin or not loading the framework.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SE.  I haven't tried Joomla 5 but I find the [cv](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#cv) method works well for cron.